# Problema al recibir datos de un formulario html a PHP

Tags: php, html

Me piden un ejercicio. Me dice que la clase Padre Punto2_PersonaB.php tenga los siguientes atributos apellido, nombre, dirección, nacimiento, sexo, disponibilidad, puesto y que una sus Clases Hijas Punto2_PostulanteB.php (cuyos atributos son los mismos que los de su padre) me pide calcular la edad del postulante y en la otra Clase Hija Punto2_EmpleadoB.php trabaja con una variable propia fecha_ingreso y me pide obtener la antigüedad, pero mi pregunta es que

¿Al recibir los datos por un formulario (Punto2_FormularioB) el mismo debe enviar los datos a la clase Padre?
¿La clase padre también debe recibir la variable fecha_ingreso a pesar de que no corresponda esencialmente a una persona si no a la Clase Hija Punto2_EmpleadoB.php?

¿Al tratar de agregar métodos de validación de campo vacíos a la clase Padre me lo pone como error y no se por qué?

```
<?php
class Punto2_PersonaB
{

    protected $apellido = $_POST["ape1"];
    protected $nombre = $_POST["nom1"];
    protected $direccion = $_POST["dir1"];
    protected $nacimiento = $_POST["nac1"];

    protected $sexo = $_POST["sexo"];
    protected $disponibilidad = $_POST["disponibilidad"];
    protected $puesto = $_POST["puesto"];
    
    //no se si esta bien que reciba la fecha ingreso
    protected $ingreso=$_POST["ing1"];
    
                            //no inicialice la fecha de ingreso
    public function __construct($surname, $name, $dress, $birth, $sex, $availability, $position)
    {
        $this->apellido= $surname;
        $this->nombre= $name; 
        $this->direccion= $dress;

        $this->nacimiento= $birth; 
        
        $this->sexo= $sex;
        $this->disponibilidad=$availability;
        $this->puesto= $position;

        
    }

                        //Si el campo apellido está vacío

        /*          no se si esta forma es la correcta
        if (empty($_POST['disponibilidad'])) {
        echo "La opcion de Disponibilidad no esta marcada".'<br>'; 
        }*/ 

        public function apellidoVacio($surname)
        {
            $this -> apellido=$surname;

            if (empty($surname)) 
            {
                echo "El campo Apellido está vacío".'<br>'; 
            }
        }
        

                        //Si el campo nombre está vacío
        public function nombreVacio($name)
        {
            $this -> nombre=$name;

            if (empty($name)) 
            {
                echo "El campo Nombre está vacío".'<br>'; 
            }
        }


                    //Si el campo direccion está vacío
        public function direccionVacia($dress)
        {
            $this -> direccion=$dress;

            if (empty($dress)) 
            {
                echo "El campo Direccion está vacío".'<br>'; 
            }
        }
     
                //Si el campo fecha nacimiento está vacío
        public function nacimientoVacio($birth)
        {
            $this -> nacimiento=$birth;

            if (empty($birth)) 
            {
                echo "El campo Fecha Nacimiento está vacío".'<br>'; 
            }
        }
      
                    //Si la opcion sexo esta vacia

    public function sexoVacio($sex)
    {
        $this -> sexo=$sex;

        if (empty($sex)) 
        {
            echo "La opcion sexo no fue marcada".'<br>'; 
        }
    }


    
                //Si la opcion disponibilidad está vacía
    public function disponibilidadVacio($availability)
    {
        $this -> disponibilidad=$availability;

        if (empty($availability)) 
        {
            echo "La opcion disponibilidad no fue marcada".'<br>'; 
        }
    }

        //Si la opcion puesto está vacío
    public function puestoVacio($position)
    {
        $this -> puesto=$position;

        if (empty($position)) 
        {
            echo "La opcion Posicion está vacía".'<br>'; 
        }          
    }
    
        //Si el campo fecha ingreso esta vacio

    public function ingresoVacio($ingreso)
    {
        $this -> ing=$ingreso;
    
        if (empty($ingreso)) 
        {
            echo "No registro Fecha de Ingreso".'<br>'; 
        }          
    }

    echo "El postulante $apellido  $nombre se inscribió en el puesto de $puesto.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Que errores tienes?

Comment: Los métodos me los marca como error claro teniendo en cuenta que esta clase Punto2_PersonaB.php recibe los valores del formulario Punto2_FormularioB.html además de las preguntas que planteo antes del codigo

Comment: La última linea de tu código (el echo de postulante) no está en ningun método. Está fuera del último método y antes del cierre de llave de la clase. Por otra parte, has definido métodos de comprobación, pero en este código en concreto no los usas. Si los llamas desde otro código(que no estás mostrando) es muy posible que estés incumpliendo `tell-dont-ask`